# How do I create a host iPhone with a static IP address for an iOS app?

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, server, tizen

I am trying to create an iOS app that uses a master iPhone as the host server for other iPhones. How do I do this using a programmatically set static IP address for the host iPhone. Essentially, I am trying to relay data over the internet from multiple iPhones to a singular iPhone without a standalone server. Looking for a solution for either Xamarin or Tizen mobile SDK, whichever works. Jailbreaking is not an option.

Note: I am a complete beginner at iOS development.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do this programatically.  The user can enable Personal hotspot on the "master" phone and the other phones can join that network and then you can use Bonjour networking to let the devices discover each other.  Alternatively if the phones are already on the same WiFi then you can just use Bonjour for discovery.  You could also use the Multipeer Connectivity framework over Bluetooth to let devices communicate.

Comment: You can not programmatically set an IP address on an iOS device. If all the iOS devices are on the same network you can use SSDP or Multicast for the device discovery process. For devices on different networks (i.e. public internet connections), you could use the Apple game services to construct peer-based relationships among devices...